# Sequelize update instance and got "SyntaxError: "undefined" is not valid JSON"

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, sequelize.js

I'm using Sequelize with expressjs for my api, I have a model named "Order" for the orders of the website im currently making, this is my model order:

```js
module.exports = (sequelize, Sequelize) => {
    const Order = sequelize.define("order", {
        uid: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING
        },
        author: {
            type: Sequelize.TEXT('long'),
            get: function() {
                return JSON.parse(this.getDataValue('author'));
            },
            set: function(author) {
                this.setDataValue('author', JSON.stringify(author));
            }
        },
        cart: {
            type: Sequelize.TEXT('long'),
            get: function() {
                return JSON.parse(this.getDataValue('cart'));
            },
            set: function(cart) {
                this.setDataValue('cart', JSON.stringify(cart));
            }
        },
        delivery: {
            type: Sequelize.TEXT('long'),
            get: function() {
                return JSON.parse(this.getDataValue('delivery'));
            },
            set: function(delivery) {
                this.setDataValue('delivery', JSON.stringify(delivery));
            }
        },
        shipmethod: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING
        },
        paymethod: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING
        },
        totalprice: {
            type: Sequelize.DECIMAL
        },
        cryptoprice: {
            type: Sequelize.DECIMAL
        },
        payed: {
            type: Sequelize.DECIMAL
        },
        promoCode: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING
        },
        status: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING
        }
    });

    return Order;
}
```

All was working good, until I try to update an order, like this:

```js
router.post('/payment/crypto', async (req, res) => {
        const {order, currency} = req.body;
        if (!order, !currency) return res.status(404).json({error: 'not found'});
        console.log(order);
        console.log(currency);
        try {
            const orderDb = await db.orders.findOne({where:{uid: order}});
            if (!orderDb) return res.status(404).json({error: 'not found'});
            const cryptoPrice = await crypto.convertPrice(currency, (parseFloat(orderDb.totalPrice) + 5));
            
            // HERE
            await db.orders.update({cryptoprice: cryptoPrice}, { where: {uid: order}});
            
            const wallet = await crypto.generateWallet(currency, '1P5ZEDWTKTFGxQjZphgWPQUpe554WKDfHQ', 'https://google.fr');
            return res.status(200).json({address: wallet.address, price: cryptoPrice});
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
            return res.status(404).json({error: error});
        }
    });
```

The findOne method works correctly, but when just after I update this order, I got this error:

```
SyntaxError: "undefined" is not valid JSON
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at model.get (shopapp\back\src\database\models\Order.model.js:9:29)
    at model.get (shopapp\back\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:2116:41)
    at model.get (shopapp\back\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:2138:33)
    at order.update (shopapp\back\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:1877:44)
    at shopapp\back\src\routes.js:132:29
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
```

The line number 9 of my Order.model.js is :

```
get: function() {
                return JSON.parse(this.getDataValue('author'));
            },
```

I dont understand cause the author column is not null, and even with the findOne I can get it

Comment: Did you check what `this.getDataValue('author')` returns?

Comment: Yep it returns the author field of my db, which is NEVER undefined, all my columns are filled with valid JSON

Comment: Can you show the value from `this.getDataValue('author')` that causes the error?

Comment: Its the following value: `{"id":000001,"first_name":"Name","last_name":"Support","username":"namesup","language_code":"fr"}`

Comment: This is not a valid JSON, the closest valid one is: `"id":1,"first_name":"Name","last_name":"Support","username":"namesup","language_code":"fr"}'`

Comment: Its 100% a valid json.

Comment: 000001 is not a valid number for JSON